# 2 compiler errors expected ';' at end of declaration list and field 'x' declared as function?

Tags: c

I'm working on  my homework for this week in my C class, and I've run into two errors when compiling the program. I'm using repl.it if that matters. The objective of the assignment is to create a program that will computerize health care records. It prompts the user for some information name, heart rate, heigh, BMI, birthday etc. then it spits them back out for the user to see, but I can't get past these two darn errors!

The two errors are as follows

```
clang version 7.0.0-3~ubuntu0.18.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)
exit status 1
main.c:9:14: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
  void read() {
             ^
             ;
main.c:9:8: error: field 'read' declared as a function
  void read() {
       ^
2 errors generated.
```

Here is the code for my program, any help would be great!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct HealthProfile {

  char firstName[10], lastName[10], gender[2];

  int height, weight, day, month, year, current_year, tHR, maxHR, HR;

  void read() {
    printf("Please enter the patient's last name \n");
    scanf("%s", lastName);
    printf("Please enter the patient's first name \n");
    scanf("%s", firstName);
    printf("Please enter the patient's gender(M/F) \n");
    scanf("%s", gender);
    printf("Please enter the current year \n");
    scanf("%d", &current_year);
    printf("Please enter the patient's birthdate as mm/dd/yyyy \n");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);
    printf("Please enter the patient's height in inches \n");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    printf("Please enter the patient's weight in pounds \n");
    scanf("%d", &weight);
    printf("Please enter the patient's heart rate \n");
    scanf("%d", &HR);
  }
  int Bmi() {
    return ((703 * weight) / (height * height));
  }
  int age() {
    return (current_year - year);
  }
  void heartRate() {
    /* as no formula and parameters are given for calculating heart rate So defaults has been taken*/

    int maxrate = 220;
    int heartrate = maxrate - age();
    int val = heartrate - HR;

    float res1 = (val * 0.4);
    float res2 = (val * 0.6);

    float targetmin = res1 + HR;
    float targetmax = res2 + HR;

    printf("\nHeart beat low rate: %.1f - %.1f", targetmin, targetmax);

    res1 = (val * 0.6);
    res2 = (val * 0.7);

    targetmin = res1 + HR;
    targetmax = res2 + HR;
    printf("\nHeart beat medium rate: %.1f - %.1f", targetmin, targetmax);

    res1 = (val * 0.7);
    res2 = (val * 0.85);

    targetmin = res1 + HR;
    targetmax = res2 + HR;
    printf("\nHeart beat high rate: %.1f - %.1f", targetmin, targetmax);
  }

  void display() {
    printf("The patient's name %s %s \n", firstName, lastName);
    printf("The patient's gender %s \n", gender);
    printf("The patient's birthdate %d/%d/%d \n", month, day, year);
    printf("The patient's height %d \n", height);
    printf("The patient's weight %d\n", weight);
    printf("The patient's age %d \n", age());
    printf("The patient's BMI %d \n", Bmi());
    heartRate();
  }
};

int main() {
  struct HealthProfile HP;
  HP.read()
  HP.display()

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't C++; a `struct` cannot contain functions. You instead have to declare those functions outside the `struct`, and have them take a handle to the structure as an argument.

```
int age(const struct HealthProfile *hp)
{
    return (hp->current_year - hp->year);
}
```

Look into the `->` and `.` operators, which are used to access and modify members of a structure.

Or, switch to a C++ compiler and use `class` instead of `struct`.

Comment: Note that `struct` and `class` can both have methods in C++ :)

Comment: @chqrlie Obviously, but structs should be used for POD only

Comment: sure, but using `scanf` in C++ is just as perverse.

Answer (score 0):

First, disclaimer, not very experienced with C or C++ so this might not be the best way to do this.

I've uploaded the full code to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yKXRtWYv) as I've had a few problems posting it in here. What I've done is move the routines out of the struct and made the routines take the struct as an argument instead. This way the struct looks like this:

`struct HealthProfile { 
char firstName[10], lastName[10], gender[2];
   int height, weight, day, month, year, current_year, tHR, maxHR, HR;};`